# Can I run NotifyOSD in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, notify-osd

I use the Gnome Shell (11.10) but am not liking its notification system. Is it possible to return to lucid - style notifications?

Like this

[image]

instead of this
[image]

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110792/gnome-3-change-system-notification-to-be-as-unity

Answer (score 1):

It exists an extension that moves the GNOME Shell notifications to the right top corner.
It's called [Shell OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/243/shell-osd/). It's not exactly what you are asking for, but it might be a good alternative.

Your notifications should now look like this:
[image]

To install it you only have to enable the slider in the webpage above.

Comment: Not working in gnome 3.4