# Gnome 3 change system notification to be as unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, notification-area, system-tray

the notification area in the bottom of screen is annoying, can i change the place and look of it to be as in unity? "at the right top and disappears when hover over it"?
and also  is there an extension to change the icons of some programs from system tray to the upper panel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run NotifyOSD in GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81459/can-i-run-notifyosd-in-gnome)

Comment: thanks @jokerdino i'll try to test the steps in the other thread. and i want to move the icons from bottom to top panel if that possible ? it is supposed to be an extension, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use notify-osd instead notification-daemon in GNOME-Shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350488/use-notify-osd-instead-notification-daemon-in-gnome-shell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

shell extension `Shell OSD` can place notifications in the upper right hand corner.

See https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/243/shell-osd/

Comment: thanks, it is working for me. the little shade down is a little bit annoying but still a good solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the author states in a comment that he abandoned the project, and it is not working with the current GNOME version (3.6)

Answer (score 7):

The extension in 'Shell OSD' is outdated, and does not seem to work with 3.6+. A alternative extension that can be used is ['Panel OSD'](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/), which is more up-to-date, and should work with Gnome Shell 3.10+.

[image: screenshots of notifaction(s)]

By default it shows the notifications on the top of the screen in the middle - using the settings *(these can be opened from the extension's webpage or Gnome Tweak Tool)* this can be changed to be on the top right:
[image: extension settings window]

The version for 3.10+ can be downloaded and installed from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/)

The 3.16 update removed compatibility with versions older than 3.10 - if you have a older version, you *might* be able to install it with:

```
cd ~ && git clone git://github.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd.git
git checkout d2289c2569d127725522eaa385b175220b28514c
cd ~/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd
./autogen.sh && make local-install
```

<sup>I haven't tested this, but basically all you should need to do is get a version before [this commit which removed the compatibility](https://github.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd/commit/aae436905ce04ac383899e4ad045353a9cfccdf9). Sources: [extension README](https://github.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd/blob/d2289c2569d127725522eaa385b175220b28514c/README.md), https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832839/2943276</sup>

Comment: What shell theme is that?

Comment: @Tim I think it was a weird version if the [Numix theme](https://launchpad.net/~numix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages)