# Use notify-osd instead notification-daemon in GNOME-Shell

Tags: gnome, notification, notify-osd

How I can replace `**notification-daemon**` (ugly notifications at bottom of screen) by

`NotifyOSD` (modern bubbles in right upper corner) ?

I found some posts about this, but GNOME at default mode don't have `Default Provider` in

`gnome.session` (only in fall-back mode).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367961/no-notifications-from-notify-osd-on-13-10

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-use-standard-gnome-notification.html

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110792/gnome-3-change-system-notification-to-be-as-unity

Answer (score 10):

The information this post provides is related:
[How can I make clicking Notify-OSD notifications bring me to their application/message?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123461/how-can-i-make-clicking-notify-osd-notifications-bring-me-to-their-application-m/123561#123561)

The system file (12.04):

```
file:///usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

contents are:

```
    [D-BUS Service]
    Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
    Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if
         [ ! -x /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = guest-restricted ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = gnome-classic-guest-restricted ]
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = default -a
              "$(basename `readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager`)" =
                    gnome-session ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu-2d ];
      then exec /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd;
      else exec /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon; fi'
```

presumably, switching the code segments that are bold will do the switch, but whether the change is actually functional is another matter. (for instance - Do both `notification-daemon` **&** `notify-osd` exist? etc.)

Another crude possibility is to rename the binaries swapping the names of `notification-daemon` and `notify-osd` however sometimes there are issues like conflicting dependencies occuring when a binary examines its own name.

I don't like posting hypothetical solutions but this is something I prefer not to try and since there has been no response perhaps this post will invigorate the audience and instigate better answers.

ref:

- [Is it possible to replace notify-osd with Gnome 3 Indicators?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47724/is-it-possible-to-replace-notify-osd-with-gnome-3-indicators?lq=1)
- [Use notify-osd instead notification-daemon in GNOME-Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350488/use-notify-osd-instead-notification-daemon-in-gnome-shell?lq=1)
- [Clickable Gnome-style notifications in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101606/gnome-style-notifications-in-unity?lq=1)
- [How to disable Unity style notification when using Gnome Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132033/how-to-disable-unity-style-notification-when-using-gnome-shell?lq=1)
- [Gnome 3 notifications are replaced with notify-osd when the machine goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72646/gnome-3-notifications-are-replaced-with-notify-osd-when-the-machine-goes-to-slee?lq=1)
- [How to install NotifyOSD-Config?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72215/how-to-install-notifyosd-config?lq=1)
-   -
-   -

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick on Ubuntu 13.10: just remove notification-deamon from startup applications:

Show start up services (hidden by default)

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

Open Startup Applications (System Tools -> Preferences -> Startup Applicazions), search for "Notification Deamon" and unable it!