# No notifications from notify-osd on 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, notification, gnome-classic, notify-osd

I recently upgraded to 13.10. Notify-OSD works correctly (`notify-send test` sends correctly the notification using gnome-shell style), but I'm not able to get notifications on volume up/down, next/previous track, brightness up/down, CD ejection events. This used to work on 13.04.

I'm using Gnome flashback session, this might me a part of the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also, for the working notifications (like notify-send), the notification is drawn with a mix of Gnome3 and unity notification styles. That's quite ugly.

It seems to be caused by notification-daemon, which comes with gnome-flashback (but conflicts with notify-osd?). Unfortunately, the package can't be removed because it is a dependency of gnome-flashback.

Killing the process fixes the notification system, i.e. only notify-osd is used and volume up/down/mute shows a notification again.

```
killall /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

In order to prevent the notification-daemon to start at each gnome-fallback session, I edited the file /etc/xdg/autostart/notification-daemon.desktop. I changed the line:

```
AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
```

To:

```
AutostartCondition=false
```

Note that this is just a workaround. I think a bug report should be filled in launchpad for this, unless it can be fixed without manually editing a file provided by a package.

Comment: You're a genius.I didn't know if I was the only one to be affected by this or if mutliple users where concerned, and as far as I searched, I didn't find anyone occurring this.

Comment: @user1527491 If this solves your problem please upvote the answer.

Comment: @speakr > I would like to, but it requires 15 reputation at least.

Comment: I filled a bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1247362

Answer (score -1):

I also found that installing xfce seems to break this on a system. Removing it and rebooting gets you notifications back.